# Why is static tension so much more difficult for me? Should I focus on it more?

Tags: execution

If I raise my straight leg 90 degrees to my torso and hold it there for several seconds, my rectus femoris (I believe it's rectus femoris) starts to explode. At the same time I can fling my leg up all the way till the knee touches the shoulder, I do banded swipers. I do have some hip flexion ability. To give another example, I do banded crunches. My abs are not the strongest abs in the world, but they do have some strength. But if I do very slow crunches, and hold it at some points for a few seconds, I don't feel strong at all, just the opposite. My torso is convulsing, shaking, especially at about 30 to 40 degrees, and I can't control it. If I have any muscle strength at all, I should be able to perform smooth, slow, controllable motions, shouldn't I (not just powerful, explosive ones)? Why is it happening? Should I incorporate more slow, static exercises (I don't like static exercises)?

Answer (score 3):

Muscles are strongest in the middle of their contraction range, becoming weaker at very long and very short muscle lengths. Furthermore, in the case of hanging leg raises, the demands of gravity are the greatest when the leg becomes fully horizontal, so there is more resistance to overcome at the top of this movement than any other part. Finally, static holds at short muscle lengths also requiring overcoming the limits of the flexibility of the antagonist muscles, the hamstrings in the case of hanging leg raises. The reason why you can do these exercises dynamically but not statically is that you don't have the strength to overcome the resistance at the top of the range of motion of these exercises, but you do have enough strength to build up momentum during the initial majority of the range of motion of the exercise, and use that momentum to carry the limb through the rest of the range of motion.

> Should I incorporate more slow, static exercises (I don't like static exercises)?

Do you have an actual need to be able to perform these static holds, such as participating in a form of dance or gymnastics that requires their demonstration? If not, then there's nothing wrong with not training them and just accepting that you aren't particularly good at these skills. There's also nothing wrong with using momentum in the dynamic versions of these exercises, as doing so puts more of the load on the muscle when it is lengthened, which is more important for hypertrophy than loading at short muscle lengths.

Comment: Does your torso shake too when you do slow crunches and hold it every now and then? If so, doesn't it bruise your ego?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev You might have an unhealthy relationship with exercise.